# problem conversion value

Tags: attiny, attiny85, attiny13

I have two functions that return an int16_t but I need to convert the ints to
char* is for an attiny13

It would be something like this

```
const char* msg = "value1()"+','+"value2()"+','+"value3()"
```

like example

```
#include "TinyRF_TX.h"

void setup(){
  // transmitter default pin is pin #2. You can change it by editing Settings.h
  setupTransmitter();
}

void loop(){

  const char* msg = "Hello from far away!";

  //send function accepts an array of bytes as first argument
  //second argument is the length of the array
  send((byte*)msg, strlen(msg));

  //make sure there's at least a TX_DELAY_MICROS delay between transmissions
  //otherwise the receiver's behavior will be undefined
  delayMicroseconds(TX_DELAY_MICROS);
```

Comment: What are you going to do with this string? If you are going to send it somewhere with `Something.print()` or `Something.write()`, you probably don't need to build it in the first place.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you will see I need to send that string using tinyRF from what I see it only allows sending strings type pchar*

Answer (score 3):

You will need to build the string yourself. Probably the easiest way is using the `sprintf()` function which will take a bunch of arguments and convert them to a string based on formatting instructions you give it.

An apropos article here...
https://www.programmingelectronics.com/sprintf-arduino/

Comment: _"for an attiny13"_ Code with nothing but avrlibc `snprintf()`ing of an `int` to a buffer takes about 1.5k of the available 1k of flash space on an attiny13. This is without involving the Arduino core or serial or anything else. This might work for an attiny85, or 45, or even 25 with not a lot of room to spare. But for an attiny13 you're going to need to do something tighter.